# Droid: How to centre text within a 9patch's defined borders

Tags: android, textview, nine-patch

I have a textview with a 9patch backdrop that has a drawn in dropshadow. The text is not centred in the defined frame but centred to the whole image dimensions including dropshadow. Checking it in the Draw9patch tool in the SDK shows the content space correctly but the text is ignoring this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toast_layout_root"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/toast_frame2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Toast text"
        android:textColor="#444444"
        android:textSize="10sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

How do I get the textview to use the 9patch definitions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way for the framework to understand that you're drawing a shadow. You need to center the frame. Measure the pixels between the frame and the edge on the right of your 9-patch, then insert that many blank pixel columns between the left edge of your frame and left edge of the 90-patch. Repeat for the top.

Adjust padding to prevent the text from overlapping the frame's edge.

Comment: Okay. Seems odd to include a content area in the 9patch and then for Android to ignore it, but just padding the left with space will do the job.

Comment: The problem with trying to set the padding on the left in xml rather than the 9-patch is that you'll need to specify the padding for every dpi version of your 9-patch and then make sure it looks right on every screen classification. If padding is in the 9-patch, all of that goes away.